# Can a struct in swift have a copy constructor

Tags: swift

I have a struct and a class:

```
class FooClass {
    var someValue: String = "123"
}
struct TestStruct {
    var aValue: Int = 12
    var clsValue: FooClass
}
```

And I want a deep copy for TestStruct, but the following code will also change clsValue in variable a:

```
var a = TestStruct(aValue: 10, clsValue: FooClass())
var b = a
b.clsValue.someValue = "abc"
```

I know the class value in the struct is copied only 'reference', but I want a deep copy for this class when I assigning a to b.

I do know c++ can define a copy constructor or override the = operator. Dose swift support something like that?

Answer (score 2):

A copy constructor is nothing more than an initializer that takes another instance of the same type. Simply define such initializers for your class and struct with the appropriate deep copies.

```
class FooClass {
    var someValue: String = "123"

    init() {
    }

    init(someValue: String) {
        self.someValue = someValue
    }

    // "Copy constructor"
    convenience init(_ other: FooClass) {
        self.init(someValue: other.someValue)
    }
}

struct TestStruct {
    var aValue: Int = 12
    var clsValue: FooClass

    init(aValue: Int, clsValue: FooClass) {
        self.aValue = aValue
        self.clsValue = FooClass(clsValue) // deep copy
    }

    // "Copy constructor"
    init(_ other: TestStruct) {
        self.init(aValue: other.aValue, clsValue: other.clsValue)
    }
}

var a = TestStruct(aValue: 10, clsValue: FooClass())
var b = TestStruct(a) // create new instance with its deep copy
b.clsValue.someValue = "abc"
print(a.clsValue.someValue) // prints 123
```

Comment: I know that would work. But you should manually write this code 'var b = TestStruct(a)'. Can I just use 'var b = a' to do the deep copy work?

Comment: @NewSelf No, since you can't redefine the `=` operator to call your "copy constructor" initializer.